# Can I encrypt the ConfigStoreConnectionString when using In-role Window Azure Cache (dedicated role)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-caching

Is there a way to encrypt the ConfigStoreConnectionString when using In-role Window Azure Cache (dedicated role)?

Right now the ConfigStoreConnectionString is stored in the ServiceConfiguration file and it's in the clear. I've been asked to encrypt the connection string using aspnet_regiis for security reasons but when I use an encrypted string the caching doesn't know how to decrypt it. Here's the section of the service config file:

```
  <Role name="ConnectCacheWorker">
    <Instances count="2" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.NamedCaches" value="xxxxxx" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.DiagnosticLevel" value="1" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.ConfigStoreConnectionString" value="xxxxxx" />
```

What's the best practice for encrypting Connection strings in the service config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this is possible. The cache plugin has to natively support this.

Comment: I hadn't been able to find a way to do this but thought maybe I was missing something. Thanks for the help Ankit.